# How to get the interface guid of USB device?

Tags: c#, .net, usb

I have tried this code, but it only retrieves the "ClassGuid". Is there a way to get the USB device's Interface Guid?

```
private void loadUsbDevices()
{
    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
        @"SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE DeviceID LIKE 'USB%'"))
    {
        ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();

        foreach (var device in collection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(((string) device.GetPropertyValue("Name")) + " ("
                        + ((string) device.GetPropertyValue("ClassGuid")) + ") "
                        + ((string)device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID")));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your device happen to use WinUSB as its driver?

Answer (score 1):

Since your device uses WinUSB as the driver, you have probably already arranged for a registry value named DeviceInterfaceGUIDs to be inserted in the registry for that device.  You can retrieve that same value using `SetupDiOpenDevRegKey` and `RegQueryValueExW`.  For some example code that does this, see this code from libusbp:

https://github.com/pololu/libusbp/blob/890379c54ef58de46afc60b9c3eccfe2bd66d523/src/windows/generic_interface_windows.c#L93

You can also find similar code in the source code of libusb.